# multiple unrelated organization single account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

is it possible to access multiple organizations that aren't linked together with a single Account?

I currently have one Account called name@org1.com he is in the organization org1 and actually can access everything in org1 on google cloud, now I actually have a second org, called org2.io and

I want to access everything with the same account called name@org1.com, however I can't see everything and after adding ownership to org2 to name@org1.com my account somehow has a lot of errors inside the GCP UI, can somebody help me how to correctly set the IAM access to have it work correctly? Or is it a bad idea to do that?

org1 has a gsuite account while org2 uses free cloud identity.

Comment: Can you provide some of the error messages you are getting? In theory, your single user can be Org super admin in both and can have role/owner at the org level in both

Comment: actually I had the wrong IAM permission. I used "owner" instead of "organization-owner"

Comment: If that fixed your issue can you write what you changed as the answer :)